# Symfony Form - form type options inside form class or Twig functions?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

It's a little hard to specify it in the title so I'm going to give a specific example. 
I created form class called **FlashcardType** in which I have `buildForm()` method and following code inside

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
{
    $builder
        ->add('exampleSentence', CheckboxType::class, [
             'label' => 'Example sentence'
        ])
        ->add('pronunciation', CheckboxType::class, [
            'label' => 'Pronunciation'
        ])
        ->add('sortBy', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Sort by',
            'choices' => [
                'Date increase' => 1,
                'Date decrease' => 2,
                'Word alphabetically' => 3,
                'Word not alphabetically' => 4
            ]
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'Submit'
    ]);
}
```

So the result form will contain 2 *checkboxes*, one *select drop-down* and *submit button*.
Inside the controller I pass this form to view by createView() method.

And to make this question shorter let's take only this first checkbox as example.
So inside Twig file I have the code as follows:

```
{# ...form code... #}
<div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4">
    {{ form_widget(form.exampleSentence, {'attr': {'class': 'form-check-input'}}) }}
    {{ form_label(form.exampleSentence, null, {
        'label_attr': {'class': 'form-check-label'}
    }) }}
</div>
{# ...form code... #}
```

For checkbox type (and not only) we can set [options outputted in the table](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html) while creating form by `formBuilder()`. But [many of these options](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-variables-reference) we can override in Twig functions. 
For this first checkbox I set label inside `buildForm()` but I can also set it inside `{{ form_label() }}` Twig function. And I can make it for many (if not for every) option and types.

So what's the difference between wrtiting options inside form builder and Twig form functions? Which of these options should we write inside builder and which of these inside Twig? Are there some good practices in this case?

Thank you in advance for all answers!

Comment: I see it as ... the form (class) is about the logic, data, structures on a semantical/formal level, while the twig stuff is for display and user experience. On average I wouldn't even add the buttons to the form class unless I have multiple different buttons, where the button pressed is relevant. (upside of removing the button: easily extendible/embeddable, you can always add `<button type="submit">...</button>`)

Comment: [Jakumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275413/jakumi) I'm sorry I'm replying only now but I had to have a little break. Could you exapand the topic, please? For example what about labels? Should I put it to the class or Twig? And referring to the `button` you mean that I can write usual HTML for elements from which I don't get any data?

Comment: I would use translation keys as labels (which in some sense is generic) and in the form it will be translated, and the translation is locale specific and for the view (and can be overridden, if it doesn't fit). yes, you can add the button in the template, since it doesn't submit data. some forms I use for both create and update actions. it's nice for the button not to be included in the form (object). this way, you can add the button yourself and give it the appropriate caption (create/update). Hope that helps ;o)